# Which function should I use for a nonlinear regression in panel data in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have a data set with different years, so it is panel data. I know what features I should use in my model for a nonlinear regression. I already used the `nls()`function for each year to find coefficients and then took an average of these coefficients.

I would like to know if it is rational to do this, or should I follow another strategy for a nonlinear regression for a panel data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get what your problem is (what is non-linear in your data/model?). One way of modelling a panel data set is to use a [dummy-variable FE model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174243/difference-between-fixed-effects-dummies-and-fixed-effects-estimator) and "control" for non-linearity in continuous variables/features by applying generalised additive models ([GAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gam/gam.pdf)) with regression splines.

I don't understand why you split up your data for regression? Why don't control `year` via indicator/dummy variables?

Comment: i already have a model and i just should find coefficients for it. and its non linear.but i realize since i have same agents and their features during years.so its a panel data.

Comment: so using nls () for a panel data gives me wrong answers?i didnt knew about this GAM !

Comment: I would not say wrong, but maybe you can do better. GAM are tools to estimate a quasi non-parametric model by using a series of linear regressions. So a really simple and robust tool, with remarkable flexibility and power. That‘s why I prefer GAM to model very complex non-linear problems. Find some examples here: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Chapter%207%20Lab.txt. It‘s code from the book „Introduction to statistical learning“ Ch. 7.

Comment: yes i am reading about it.and it looks so interesting .thank for your recommend